# General guidance with proofs, fields in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm taking a linear algebra course and I'm having a lot of issues answering proofs, most of the questions seem "a given" or that they derive from themselves, and I'm just stuck staring at the book.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to approach proofs, what I'm even allowed to "use".

For example,

Prove that

```
-(-a) = a
```

Seems a given, it seems to be derived directly from a statement in the book, and I don't know how to further prove something like that.

Another example is

Prove that

```
(-a)b = a(-b)= -(ab)
```

In this case, it's hard for me to understand what am I even allowed to do?
how much am I allowed to presume and lean on normal math?
As every property (Commutativity, Associativity, etc..) is defined and tested it's hard to know what you can and cant use.

for example, am I allowed to derive from the question that?

```
(-a)b +ab = 0
```

In short, I need guidance in how to mentally approach these kinds of questions, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **What I'm even allowed to "use"** depend on in which algebra you are working on.

Comment: For considering $-(-a)=a$, you should be able to use the additive inverse and show that $-(-a)$ and $a$ have the same additive inverse, and thus are equal.  It looks like most of these questions relate to that particular concept.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show how you might prove something like your first question and hopefully that will give you an idea of what this kind of proof is supposed to look like. You're trying to show that $-(-a) = a$. This seems really evident, so how do we formally prove it? I'm going to use a lot more words than is really necessary to try and provide clarity for you here, but the important thing is that you understand what is going on.

The way I would approach this is to go back to the formal definition of $-x$ in an abstract vector space. Given a vector $v$ in a vector space $V$ we define the symbol $-v$ to be the unique vector such that
$$
v+(-v) = 0
$$
This is what we mean by the symbol $-a$. The existence of such a vector is guaranteed by the vector space axioms and uniqueness is simple to prove, so the symbol makes sense. Now we are trying to show that $-(-a)) = a$. Now we know from the definition that $a+(-a) = 0$. We are trying to show that a particular vector $a$ is the inverse of $-a$, i.e. $-(-a)$. Let $b = -a$. Then the fact that we know $a+(-a) = 0$ implies that $a+b = 0$. By the uniqueness of $-b$, this means that $a = -b$, but $b = -a$ so we have that $a = -b = -(-a)$ as desired.